# MVC app does not show selected values on a form reedition

Tags: forms, input, select-options

I am building a Framework7 MVC app and found myself in a dead end alley. I have a form which I need to evaluate. This form contains selects. I am using localStorage to store the form values and everything works OK in that sense, I mean everything is stored correctly. ¿What is the issue? When I fill the form I answer some questions on textareas inputs, select inputs and inputs. everything goes fine until I try to reedit the form, then everything is display correctly on the form, including the score i got from my previous answers, but, the selects appears as if I have never touch them. Their previously selected value is stored but not display on the form. I have found that the issue is caused by the fact that I have set numerical values to the options values but what the form show is "yes" or "no". If I change the option values to "yes" or "no" then the form displays correctly but I need to set "5" or "0" because I need to evaluate the user's answers.

This is my code

The form

```
<li style="margin-top:-10px;">
<input style="visibility:hidden;height:1px;" value="0" name="choice" onchange="checkTotal()"/>
<input style="visibility:hidden;height:1px;" value="1" type="checkbox" name="choice" onchange="checkTotal()" checked="on">
</li>
<li><div class="item-content">1. ¿Sueles quejarte de sentirte mal?</div>
<div class="item-content">
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-input">
<select name="pr1" id="pr1" onchange="checkTotal()">
<option class="item-inner" value="5">No</option>
<option class="item-inner" value="0">Si</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item-content">En tal caso,</div>
<div class="item-content">
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-input">
<textarea class="resizable" id="pr1notes" placeholder="¿cuál es la causa?">{{model.pr1notes}}</textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

The functions on the editController

```
function init(query){
var protections = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Protections"));
if (query && query.id) {
protection = new Protection(_.find(protections, { id: query.id }));
state.isNew = false;
}
else {
protection = new Protection({ isFavorite: query.isFavorite });
state.isNew = true;
}
View.render({ model: protection, bindings: bindings, state: state, doneCallback: saveProtection });

showSelectedValues();
}

function showSelectedValues(){
var fieldNames = protection.getSelectFields();
for (var i = 0, len = fieldNames.length; i < len; i++) {
var itemname =  fieldNames[i];
var selectObj = document.getElementById(itemname);
if (selectObj!=null) {
var objOptions = selectObj.options;
var selIndex=0;
for (var j = 0, len2 = objOptions.length; j < len2; j++) {
if ((objOptions[j].label).localeCompare(protection[itemname])==0){
selIndex=j;
}
}
selectObj.options[selIndex].setAttribute("selected","selected");
}else{
}
}
}
```

and the model

```
Protection.prototype.setValues = function(inputValues, extras) {
for (var i = 0, len = inputValues.length; i < len; i++) {
var item = inputValues[i];
if (item.type === 'checkbox') {
this[item.id] = item.checked;
}
else {
this[item.id] = item.value;
}

}

for (var i = 0, len = extras[0].length; i < len; i++) {
var item = extras[0][i];
if((item.id).localeCompare("pr1notes")==0)   {this[item.id] = item.value;}

}

console.log('starting loop for extras 3...');
for (var i = 0, len = extras[2].length; i < len; i++) {
var item = extras[2][i];

this[item.name] = item.value;

}

};

Protection.prototype.validate = function() {
var result = true;
if (_.isEmpty(this.prdate)
) {result = false;}
return result;
};

Protection.prototype.getSelectFields = function() {
    return ['pr1'];

}
```

What should I change in order to keep my "5" or "0" values on the select options while the form options still show "yes" or "no" to the user just like this: `<select name="pr1" id="pr1" onchange="checkTotal()"><option class="item-inner" value="5">No</option><option class="item-inner" value="0">Si</option></select>`?

need anything else to help you understand the issue?

Comment: I have solved the issue. For those who might have this or similar trouble now or in the future, this is one of those head aches caused by something so tiny that we pass it over and over and do not realize. Just simply change the label to value in this line of the controller ```if ((objOptions[j].label).localeCompare(protection[itemname])==0){```. now it should be like this ```if ((objOptions[j].value).localeCompare(protection[itemname])==0){```. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution

```
function init(query){
var protections = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Protections"));
if (query && query.id) {
protection = new Protection(_.find(protections, { id: query.id }));
state.isNew = false;
}
else {
protection = new Protection({ isFavorite: query.isFavorite });
state.isNew = true;
}
View.render({ model: protection, bindings: bindings, state: state, doneCallback: saveProtection });

showSelectedValues();
}

function showSelectedValues(){
var fieldNames = protection.getSelectFields();
for (var i = 0, len = fieldNames.length; i < len; i++) {
var itemname =  fieldNames[i];
var selectObj = document.getElementById(itemname);
if (selectObj!=null) {
var objOptions = selectObj.options;
var selIndex=0;
for (var j = 0, len2 = objOptions.length; j < len2; j++) {
if ((objOptions[j].value).localeCompare(protection[itemname])==0){
selIndex=j;
}
}
selectObj.options[selIndex].setAttribute("selected","selected");
}else{
}
}
}
```

Just changed this line

```
if ((objOptions[j].label).localeCompare(protection[itemname])==0){
    selIndex=j;
```

and changed `.label` for `.value`.